# Update query with RxJava2 type return give an error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Tags: rx-java2, android-room

Here is the the code snippet that give the Cursor conversion issue :

```
@Query("UPDATE profile SET profilePicture=:newProfilePicture WHERE firstName = :first AND lastName = :last")
fun updateProfilePicture(
    newProfilePicture: ByteArray,
    first: String,
    last: String
) : Completable
```

What I have tried :

- Remove the `lastName` from the query and return `Single<String>`.
- Return `Single<List<String>>`
- Return `Single<Void>`

**Gradle**

```
def room_version = "2.2.5"
implementation "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$room_version"
```

But nothing of them has worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> @Query methods: Room supports return values of type `Publisher`, `Flowable`, and `Observable`.

As stated by the doc the supported type for Query methods are : Publisher, Flowable and Observable. So the first thing to fix is to change from Completable to one of the supported type.

After making the fix I still have the problem in the generated code. I have found a *compilation error* because the expected type was `Integer`. So the fix that I made is I changed from RxJava2 supported type to `Int` and I wrapped it later to become `Single`.

IMO this is just a workaround.

The issue comes from the fact that I was using :

```
kapt 'androidx.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

inseat of

```
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```